# Proper genitive on a names with pre-existing genitive as a name

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, genitive-construction

I have a special case that I can't tell how to cover using the generally googlable rules.

There was a person called Thyrén. He created a company and named it after himself. Now, that's been done long time ago in Sweden, with no English in sight. Hence the company's name, as per Swedish grammar, became *Thyréns*. Eventually, it became a term and few will consider it *of Mr. Thyrén*. In fact, there are common Swedish names ending with an "s" without any connotation to ownership or pluralization.

Now, that the company enters the global market, It's called simple and plain as *Thyrens*. Swedes will pronounce it as originally, while foreigners will tend to go *thayh-reens*.

What should I put in the text when I'm referring to that company's belongings?

*Thyrens' staff* or *Thyrens staff* or, perhaps, *Thyrens'es staff*?

Comment: The pen belonging to Thomas is Thomas' pen. It is often pronounced as "Thomases", though.

Comment: We [don't *usually* use the possessive form](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Tesco+staff%2CTesco%27s+staff&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) in such contexts. It's usually just the plain "noun adjunct" form ***Tesco staff***, but possessive ***Tesco's staff*** does occur, and I think it would be stretching a point to say that orthography is "wrong". Note that it isn't easy to *hear* the difference even with ***Tesco's***, and it would be impossible to tell by sound with, say, ***Morrisons' staff*** (which would ***never*** be pronounced ***Morrisonses***).

Comment: ...a couple of centuries ago it was [almost always ***Thomas's hospital***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Thomas%27s+Hospital%2CThomas%27+Hospital&year_start=1819&year_end=1919&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10), but today [we're as likely as not to discard the second **s**.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Thomas%27s+Hospital%2CThomas%27+Hospital&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10)

Comment: ...see also [***Boots staff***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Boots+staff%2CBoots%27+staff&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) for a British company whose name ends in 's'. Few if any Brits would ever refer to ***Bootses staff*** in the spoken medium.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question is more generally about the company's possessions, not just its staff, which idiomatically uses the company name adjectivally. With other things, we use 's: "Boots's market capitalization" or "Boots's reputation", NOT "Boots market capitalization" nor "Boots reputation".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Would you care posting that as an answer? It seems that the the currently present one isn't aligning with your comment and it would be interesting to get a comparison and discussion on the topic.

Comment: @gotube: In the UK we very rarely write (and virtually *never* say) the possessive /s/ after the apostrophe ([chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Boots%27s%2C%28Boots%27%29-%28Boots%27s%29&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3)). For some reason [American English over the past two decades](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Boots%27s%2C%28Boots%27%29-%28Boots%27s%29&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) has suddenly rapidly adopted that unnecessarily extended format. But Boots the chemist is *British*, so go figure.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the Americas we put the "s" after the apostrophe for proper names that end with "s", and just the the apostrophe for other nouns that end in "s".

Answer (score 2):

You should follow whatever practice you normally follow for singular proper nouns ending in the letter "s" with the "z" sound.

*The Chicago Manual of Style* (14th ed., section 6.19) says:

> The possessive of singular nouns is formed by the addition of an apostrophe and an *s*.

However, later (section 6.30) it describes some alternative practices, which include adding an apostrophe only (without "s") to words such as "Thyrens". It then says:

> The University of Chicago Press prefers the procedures outlined above (6.24-27). It is willing, however, to accept other ways of handling these situations if they are consistently followed throughout a manuscript.

Using "Thyrens" as an attributive noun ("Thyrens staff") is possible, as you suggest. However, I've never seen a possessive written like "Thyrens'es staff"; I would avoid that.

Comment: What if it's not about the company's staff? Let's say I want to inquire whether something belongs to you or to the firm. I would ask: *is it yours or Thyrens?* then? It looks immensely wrong...   :)

Comment: Yes, "Thyrens" couldn't be an attributive noun there (first, because it is in a predicative position and second, because it wouldn't be parallel with the possessive form "yours"), so it would have to be in possessive form.

Comment: And in such case, we'd say: *is it yours or Thyrens'* (with the ending apostrophe), right?

Comment: @KonradViltersten If that's how you form the possessive of "Thyrens", then yes, that's how you would write it.

Answer (score 0):

We [don't usually use the possessive form](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Tesco%20staff%2CTesco%27s%20staff&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) in such contexts...

[image]

As you can see, it's usually just the plain "noun adjunct" form ***Tesco staff***, but possessive ***Tesco's staff*** does occur, and I think it would be stretching a point to say that orthography is "wrong".

Note that it isn't easy to hear the difference even with ***Tesco's***, and it would be impossible to tell by sound with, say, ***Morrisons' staff*** (which is never pronounced ***Morrisonses***).

---

Here's a chart showing the two orthographies of [***Boots staff***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Boots%20staff%2CBoots%27%20staff&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) - a British company whose name ends in /***s***/. Few if any Brits would ever refer to ***Bootses staff*** in speech.

[image]

Comment: So, if I'm to simplify it a bit deviating from the exactness in the full metal jacket answer of yours, I hear that the short answer is: *Thyrens' staff* (the exact object of ownership being poorly chosen, perhaps). So, the application would be: *it is Thyrens', not yours* if reprimanding somebody or such. Correct? (Or, rather, "correct'ish".)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But I would just add that *some* people (not me! :) would be more inclined to adopt the relatively less common double-s pronunciation (and thus also *write* the possessive /s/ after the apostrophe) in that exact context. Precisely *because* it's "emphatic contradiction" (all speakers would tend to pronounce ***Thyrens'*** there with heavier stress, whether or not they added the extra /s/).

Comment: -1 Again, the question wasn't about the word "staff", but about possessions of the company in general. "Staff" idiomatically is used without any possession markers, as if the company's name is an adjective, but this is not the case with other nouns, so this answer is incorrect and misleading.

Comment: @gotube: As I think I already pointed out, I don't recognise your contention that ***staff*** is some kind of special case in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Which of these do you think is correct: "*I'm keeping an eye on Thyrens market position*" or "*I'm keeping an eye on Thyrens' market position*". (only difference being the apostrophe)

Comment: @gotube: I don't care much about "correct orthography" in contexts like that, where it's impossible to reflect the difference in speech. But I'd include the apostrophe myself. Note that for a British company whose name *doesn't* end in /s/, and which *isn't* often "extended" like ***Tesco's*** and ***Sainsbury's***, I would definitely not expect to discard the possessive in, say, ***I'm keeping an eye on Finefare's market position***. Plain ***Finefare*** there would be weird.